# Using LastInsertId Multiple times, PHP PDO

Tags: php, database, insert, pdo

I have this registration stuff, and I want to 3 tables to be filled with data as soon as the user clicks add user

the tables were:

```
users
roles
status
user_role
user_status
```

The system must insert the data as follows
**users table:**

```
 username
 password
```

**user_roles**

```
user_id
default value
```

**user_status**

```
user_id
default value
```

i used pdo begin transaction stuff and commit stuff to  make this work...
this worked great when I used it on just two tables, however when i decide to use another table and do the same code pattern, it did not work at all.

here are the codes:

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
        VALUES (:user,:pass)");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':user'=> $data['user'],
            ':pass'=> Hash::create('sha256', $data['pass'], HASH)
        ));

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_role (user_id, role_id) VALUES (:user, :role)");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':user' => $this->db->lastInsertId(),
            ':role' => 3
        ));

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_status (user_id, status_id) VALUES (:user, :status)");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':user' => $this->db->lastInsertId(),
            ':status' => 1
        ));

        $this->db->commit();
```

What do you think is the problem, I also doubt this is some kind of a syntax error, but I could not find, it, so my last resort is to ask, for I am not sure also if this works on 3 tables. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you should commit each `INSERT` since no changes made in database in transaction body.

Comment: what do you mean by commit each `insert` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your first insert:

`$insertID = $this->db->lastInsertId();`

then in the following `INSERTS`

```
':user' => $insertID,
```

Comment: i guess that will definitely work, i got the idea, i will try it now.